# Catch the last process before an out of memory error

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, wrapper

I have a system running a JVM as a windows services that is running 4 processes. The JVM is configured to auto-restart when it encounters error.

I recently encountered this issue wherein the JVM stops executing one of the processes and is simply hogging CPU usage (90+%), but no exception was encountered in the logs. However, after about 30 minutes it showed an Out-Of-Memory Error and then proceeds to restart.

I did use -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to generate a hprof file which I opened with Eclipse MAT, but I do not understand how to trace it back to my code.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to throw an OOME when the JVM hangs instead of waiting for the Stacktrace to print the error?
2. Is there any way to catch the last process that is running before the hanging? Or a way to find out which process might have a leak.

Many Thanks!

Comment: You should collect GC logs, OOME can be also thrown if the jvm is sepnding most of the time running GC instead of application. And then you would see high cpu usage but no progress on calculations. But you can't just guess that without checking gc logs.

Comment: My guess is your heap ran out of space and your JVM is performing GC continuously to retain space. After a while it gave up. In MAT check histogram and find out which objects are consuming more heap. Based on your application you may have to analyze multiple dumps to conclude. Just by seeing GC logs and heap dump you can't narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you make the MEGABYTES field large enough in this example you can make your JVM throw an OutOfMemoryError and dump the stack trace:

```
public class MemoryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MEGABYTES = 1000;
        memoryTest(MEGABYTES);
    }
    public static void memoryTest(int megabytes){
        showMemory("Begin");
        try {
            useMemory(megabytes);
        } catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
            System.out.println("About to run out of memory!");
            // also dump the stack trace
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.gc();
        showMemory("After GC");
    }
    static void useMemory(int megaBytes){
        final int MB = 1024*512;
        byte[][] bytes = new byte[megaBytes][];
        for(var c=0;c<megaBytes;c++){
            bytes[c] = new byte[MB];
        }
        showMemory("After useMemory");
    }
    static void showMemory(String heading){
        long allocated = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/(1024*1024);
        long used = ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/(1024*1024));
        long max = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/(1024*1024));
        long available = max - used;

        System.out.println(heading);
        System.out.println("\tVM Allocated Memory is: " + allocated +"MB");
        System.out.println("\tUsed Memory is: " + used +"MB");
        System.out.println("\tAvailable Memory is: " + available +"MB");
    }

}
```